# minimal proper vertex coloring.

Tags: graph-theory, coloring

[image]

Hi,

So as exam revision I'm trying to solve this from a past paper for (I) I think it is fairly straightforward Brookes theorem is the relevant theorem and I found a  minimal proper vertex coloring easy. But for (ii) I can't see how $χ ≤ 4$ when there are multiple vertices of degree 5 can anyone explain it to me?

Comment: [Four Color Theorem](https://www.cantorsparadise.com/the-four-color-theorem-8eece6ab6b12)

Comment: What is the chromatic number of (i), is it $3$ or $4$? It doesn't look that easy to me but it's been a long time since I took graph theory.

Comment: Remember, you are coloring *vertices* so it is ok for the degree of a particular vertex to be quite large. (For example, think of a snowflake with 101 vertices with just one vertex of degree 100 and all the others with degree 1.  The vertices of such a graph can be properly colored with only 2 colors.)

Comment: You are correct that [Brooke's Theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Brooks%27_theorem) gives an upper bound of $\chi \leq 5$ for graph (ii), but the Four Color Theorem gives a tighter upper bound of just $\chi \leq 4$ for this graph.

Answer (score 1):

You are correct that [Brooke's Theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Brooks%27_theorem) gives an upper bound of $\chi \leq 5$ for graph (ii), but the Four Color Theorem gives a tighter upper bound of just $\chi \leq 4$ for this graph.

Note that both graphs contain $K_3$ as a subgraph, so $3\leq \chi \leq 4$.

I think you will have to work thru the cases (by trial and error) to figure out whether the chromatic number of each graph is, in fact, the lower bound of 3 or the upper bound of 4.  (That is, you will need to demonstrate you can properly color the vertices with just three colors, or alternatively that it is impossible to properly color the vertices with just three colors.)

Answer (score 0):

For (ii), $\chi \leq 4$ follows from the four color theorem:

Observe that the graph is planar, hence by the cited theorem $4$-colorable.